# System.InvalidCastException when using Webbrowser and Background worker class C#

Tags: c#

```
public void bgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < idscount; i++)
        {
            if (bgw.CancellationPending == true)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                bgw.ReportProgress(i + 1);
                webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("txtIDCardNo").SetAttribute("Value", "\"" + value + "\"");
                webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("btnIDCard").InvokeMember("click");
                webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(WaitElement);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
            }
        }
    }
```

I end up in "An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll but was not handled in user code". I am not able to understand, If I run same code without background worker class it works but inside background worker class it doesnt. Please help me out.

Comment: All the calls to UI must be done in main thread, Invoke the calls to the WebBrowser.

Comment: Not an answer, but generally wondering. Why are you adding an event handler inside the loop for every iteration? And generally using Sleep inside a background worker is a bad idea. You should try to resolve race conditions without resorting to sleep.

Comment: The form does not respond for long thats why used background worker. Also, I used for loop to run the webbrowser element click, but the loop processes so fast that only the last result is displayed.